# Pandas Slinear Interpolation grouping by another column

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
testing = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,np.nan,np.nan,7,1,np.nan,np.nan,7], 
                        'col2':['01-MAY-17 15:47:00','01-MAY-17 15:57:00',
                            '07-MAY-17 15:47:00','07-MAY-17 22:07:00',
                            '01-MAY-17 15:47:00','01-MAY-17 15:57:00',
                            '07-MAY-17 15:47:00','07-MAY-17 22:07:00'],
                        'Customer_id':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})
```

I need to interpolate the missing values in the first column according to each customer (in this case, it wouldn't make a difference but since I have some customers that either their first or their last have missing values as missing, I really need to keep it separate).

Before, I was using this:

```
testing.groupby('Customer_id').apply(lambda group: group.interpolate(method= 'linear'))
```

but this assumes that every point is spaced equally, and as the second column is the date time of when each record was collected, it can be seen that it is not.

In order to change this in such a way that it would take the different spacing into account I passed col2 to the index, and interpolated with slinear

```
testing['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(testing['col2'])
testing['index1'] = testing.index
testing = testing.set_index('col2')
testing.apply(lambda group: group.interpolate(method= 'slinear'))
test_int=testing.interpolate(method='slinear')
test_int['col2'] = test_int.index
test_int = test_int.set_index('index1')
test_int
```

but this does not take into account the different customers. How could I do a group by for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, once you have `set_index` the column with date, then you can use the `method='index'` in the `interpolate` per group such as:

```
testing.col2 = pd.to_datetime(testing.col2)
print (testing.set_index('col2').groupby('Customer_id')
              .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method= 'index')).reset_index())
                 col2       col Customer_id
0 2017-05-01 15:47:00  1.000000           A
1 2017-05-01 15:57:00  1.006652           A
2 2017-05-07 15:47:00  6.747228           A
3 2017-05-07 22:07:00  7.000000           A
4 2017-05-01 15:47:00  1.000000           B
5 2017-05-01 15:57:00  1.006652           B
6 2017-05-07 15:47:00  6.747228           B
7 2017-05-07 22:07:00  7.000000           B
```